# How to implement widevine in electron app

Tags: ember.js, electron, widevine

I am having problems to play widevine content in electron. I am trying to convert ember-app to electron app. Except widevine content everything works great, Version info are:

- Shaka 2.02
- Electron 1.4.13(Chromium 53)
- Electron Packager 8.4.0
- Widevine v1.4.8.903

I used http://electron.atom.io/docs/tutorial/using-widevine-cdm-plugin/ docs. In order to check my player i load shaka-demo app.

I included widevine like this

`` app.commandLine.appendSwitch('widevine-cdm-path', path.join(__dirname, `./widevine/1.4.8.903/_platform_specific/linux_x64/libwidevinecdmadapter.so`));
app.commandLine.appendSwitch('widevine-cdm-version', '1.4.8.903'); ``

Also added `plugins: true`. When i load `mainWindow.loadURL('https://shaka-player-demo.appspot.com/');`  to play widevine content it's disabled. I have tried `navigator.plugins` still can not play widevine content

Answer (score 0):

This should be a comment (but I don't have enough reputation). I think you don't need the dot before widevine folder `./widevine` when using `path.join`